# Use a custom ID type in mongodb usyng python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Im using mongodb to as a storage backend for some of my information in a Django 1.5 app.

Every document stored in the mongodb collection has an _id field which is a dict composed of several strings.
Now when I try to retrieve this information I map the document to a model class using mongoengine:

```
from mongoengine import *

class MyClass(Document):
    _id = DictField()
```

At the view I do:

```
documents = MyClass.objects
print documents
```

When I call the view I get a `TypeError`

```
TypeError at /viewname/
id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <type 'dict'>
```

Even worse is that when I use the save rutine

```
obj = MyClass({"tag":"sometag"})
obj.save()
```

I get the exat same error, but at the db collection the document with `_id={"tag":"sometag"}` was created.

Any ideas of what could be happening? It could be the same that is happening  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500566/typeerror-at-accounts-login-id-must-be-an-instance-of-str-unicode-objectid)

Note: I tried ussing the EmbeddedDocumentField but the results are the same (the error takes my Embedded class name instead of 'dict')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it:

I was missing the `primary_key` argument. If I change it at the model:

```
class MyClass(Document):
    id = DictField(primary_key=True)
```

It starts working at both operations, read and write.

Here is the official doc: [Mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/document-instances.html#document-ids)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use dict for `_id` field, use  a hash of that dictionary.

Eg.  sha1 of the json representation of the dictionary , or just `hash` if number of records are not that much.

Comment: Sorry for me, I am not the only one interacting with this data, so the Id is already given and I do mostly read operations on it.